# Нужна ли запятая перед "страдающих"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Братья наши меньшие подходят для людей (?) страдающих от одиночества, поскольку питомец станет другом и членом семьи.

Answer (score 2):

В предложении есть причастный оборот, который стоит после *определяемого слова*. Определяемое слово я выделил *курсивом*, а сам оборот – **жирным шрифтом**:

> Братья наши меньшие подходят для *людей* (?) **страдающих от одиночества**, поскольку питомец станет другом и членом семьи.

Есть такое правило:

> Если причастный оборот стоит после определяемого слова, то он выделяется запятыми.

Из этого правила следует, что

> запятая нужна.